# pass parameter and reference in an update function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, reference, sql-update

So I have a function `select_id_from_table(_t)`. It chooses certain column of the table (_t) where _t is a table name as a parameter. 
I call it like `SELECT select_id_from_table('tablename')`.Now I want to create another function where the function does something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(_u type1, _t type2) returns void as $$
BEGIN
UPDATE (_u) set score=score+1 where _u.id in _t.id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The problem is it can not pass the parameter properly. And also what should type1 and type2 be? _u and _t are both names of tables. I have tried:

```
$$begin
create temp table lid as (select * from select_id_from_table(_t));
execute format ('update '||quote_ident(_u) ||' set score= score+1 where 
'||quote_ident(_u) ||'.id_ in (
select * from select_id_from_table ('||quote_ident(_t)||') as 
abc )');
end;$$
```

I also tried creating a temp table, select `select_id_from_table(_t)`into that temp table and make reference of it later. But I still don't know how to quote it in `execute format('')`. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `select_id_from_table` is a function returning `SETOF <something>` and that the return type can be cast to `text`.

I didn't test it, but I would do it similar to this:

```
DECLARE
   in_clause text;
BEGIN
   SELECT string_agg(quote_literal(t::text), ', ') INTO in_clause
      FROM select_id_from_table(_u) s(t);
   EXECUTE format ('UPDATE %I
                    SET score = score + 1
                    WHERE %I.id_ =ANY (' || in_clause || ')',
                    _u, _u);
END;
```

Comment: I change to string_agg(t::text, ',') and where %I.id_ in (..) then it works. Thank you!